# Unable to catch error thrown in then block

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I am trying to catch error when using knex to add entries into the database. The error is properly caught in the catch block of insertData arrow function and console logged. However, when I throw another error in there to bubble it to the next function (handleIncomingData) it doesn't get caught properly and I get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. Here is the code for the two functions.

```
/**
 * Wrapper function for inserting data into the database
 * @param data
 * @param tableName
 * @param formatMethod
 */
const insertData = (data, tableName, formatMethod) => {
    knex(tableName).insert(formatMethod(data))
        .then(() => console.log(`Entries added to ${ tableName }`))
        .catch((err) => { console.log(err); throw err;})
}

/**
 * Handle the incoming data
 * @param data
 */
const handleIncomingData = (data) => {
    const { item, sales_line_discount, sales_price, campaign_target_group, } = data;
    
    try {
        if (item) {
            insertData(item, 'item', formatItems);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I've also copied in the errors:

```
Error: insert into `item` (`base_unit_of_measure`, `blocked`, `item_disc__group`, `last_date_modified`, `sku`, `unit_price`) values ('M', 0, 'DE05', '2018-09-05', '0100444', '5.593') - Duplicate entry '0100444' for key 'item.items_sku_uindex'
    at Packet.asError (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:712:17)
    at Query.execute (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:425:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10) {
  code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
  errno: 1062,
  sqlState: '23000',
  sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry '0100444' for key 'item.items_sku_uindex'"
}
(node:70871) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: insert into `item` (`base_unit_of_measure`, `blocked`, `item_disc__group`, `last_date_modified`, `sku`, `unit_price`) values ('M', 0, 'DE05', '2018-09-05', '0100444', '5.593') - Duplicate entry '0100444' for key 'item.items_sku_uindex'
    at Packet.asError (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:712:17)
    at Query.execute (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:425:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/sw/Projects/navision-middleware/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
(node:70871) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:70871) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

To my best knowledge the error should've just bubbled up. I am at loss on how to debug this. I suppose this is not something specific to knex but rather to lack of some basic knowledge in JS. Any help will be much welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not `await` or `.then` on the call to `insertData`, the exception likely is not thrown before the code it out of the `try` block.

I've simplified the code into a working JavaScript example of being able to catch the error at the higher function.

1. We return the promise from `insertData`
2. We `.catch` on that returned promise

```js
const insertData = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('oops')))
        .then(() => console.log(`Entries added`))
        .catch((err) => { console.log(`insertData: ${err}`); throw err;})
}

const handleIncomingData = () => {
    insertData().catch((err) => console.log(`handleIncomingData: ${err}`))
}

handleIncomingData();
```

TypeScript is exactly the same but with `new Promise<void>`
[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlpApgJygEQIZQzAvDACgEo8A+GAbwCgZaZlEoBXZMGMRAdxgAVkQAtnAiIAPADcQcACakCBBhBAAbcYgA09RACtEwKCVzkRUACpwBiEEyjzD5Brv0EA5CBAAHCC6K+adAIA6KAALRDA7MhhQSBVEQOUQAHMCAAMAUTAoZDhECBgMaWlEaVS-AKDgLGAQ+RRke0po8CVleMSU1IQRVExsAC4YABIKeoBfMoBuGFD+bnrJsaIqMaoqGOgYEIwwaTaASTBQITAkvpx8YijqAO6UdCwMYkCqqBq65AaojbiE5LTtrsDkdBAgzo9BiNxmVlqsqIC9ohDscwediJMqEA)

Here is a version with async/await, where again the key is that both are `async` and are `await`ed in the `try` block.

```js
const insertDataA = async() => {
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve()));
    throw 'oops';
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`insertDataA: ${err}`);
    throw err;
  }
}

const handleIncomingDataA = async() => {
  try {
    await insertDataA();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`handleIncomingDataA: ${err}`);
  }
}

handleIncomingDataA();
```

Comment: OK, huge thanks! I was already expecting that is an issue with promises somewhere. Then if I wanted to use the function yet another place, I would have to return the inserData().catch ... promise and do another .catch, right?

Also - in reality I have 4 calls to insertData in a row, do all of them need to have that .catch expression or is there a way I could call all 4 and then catch any error that arises from any of those four?

Comment: If I make handleIncomingData async and put await in front of the insertData call I would expect it to work but it doesn't. Why?

AFAIK async/await and .then.catch are the same thing just using different syntax. For now the promise syntax feels much more natural but I can't understand how the async await works.

Comment: @Helv I've added an example of the same code but with `async`/`await`. Hope that helps.